# How to add a Gesture Recognizer to a RichTextView nested on UIView?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I want to add a Gesture Recognizer to a Rich Text View that is basically a UIView with more features that I put inside of a normal UIView named "superiorView" , I downloaded the package from Cocoa Pods :

https://cocoapods.org/pods/RichTextView

I have tried the following code, but didn't work:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){

     super.viewDidLoad()


    let richTextView = RichTextView(
                        input: "hello",
                        latexParser: LatexParser(),
                        font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize + 2),
                        textColor: UIColor.white,
                        isSelectable: false,
                        isEditable: false,
                        frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: superiorView.frame.width, height: superiorView.frame.height),
                        completion: nil
                    )


    richTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.clickLabel_1(_:)))
        tapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1


            richTextView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)


           superiorView.addSubview(richTextView)

}



@objc func clickLabel_1(_ sender:UIGestureRecognizer ){
        print("CLICKKKK 1 !")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring the gesture recognizer but nowhere in your code are you adding it to the richTextView:

```
    richTextView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture) // add gesture recognizer to text view.
```